I'm trying to use SQL to create a temporary table that combines two tables, then counts the values in one column - what am I missing?
CREATE TEMP TABLE minuteSleeps
AS
    SELECT
        secondMinuteSleep.Id AS ID, 
        secondMinuteSleep.date AS TIMES, 
        secondMinuteSleep.Value AS VALUE, 
        secondMinuteSleep.logId as LOGID 
    FROM 
        `case-study-438019.FitBit.secondMinuteSleep` AS secondMinuteSleep
    JOIN 
        `case-study-438019.FitBit.minuteSleep` AS minuteSleep  
             ON secondMinuteSleep.value = minuteSleep.value

SELECT COUNT(value) 
FROM minuteSleeps; 

I tried to create a temporary table called minute sleeps that combines the two tables, scondMinuteSleep and minuteSleep. I want to join the two tables then count the non null values in the column, but instead, I keep getting an error:

Syntax error: Unexpected keyword SELECT at [15:1]

I think I may be missing something or the way its set up could be wrong I'm not sure though because this is my first time trying to write code using SQL on my own

Perhaps ;  before select as end previous operator.

You might want to use a column name other than 'value' since that appears to be a reserved word. I'm not familiar with BigQuery, so that's just a guess. In MS-SQL you can refer to such a column name by using [] around the word.  Not sure if that's the case with BigQuery. Since it's an alias in a temp table, you could just use a word other than value to verify. Something like `secondMinuteSleep.Value AS SLEEPVALUE'

@ValNik suggest posting that as an answer instead of comment

Try this:
BEGIN


CREATE TEMP TABLE minuteSleeps
AS (
    SELECT
        secondMinuteSleep.Id AS ID, 
        secondMinuteSleep.date AS TIMES, 
        secondMinuteSleep.Value AS VALUES, 
        secondMinuteSleep.logId as LOGID 
    FROM 
        `case-study-438019.FitBit.secondMinuteSleep` AS secondMinuteSleep
    JOIN 
        `case-study-438019.FitBit.minuteSleep` AS minuteSleep  
             ON secondMinuteSleep.value = minuteSleep.value);

SELECT COUNT(VALUES) 
FROM minuteSleeps; 

END;

